# Desktop Gadgets and Widgets to Assist Programmers

Tags: windows-desktop-gadgets

Does the collective genius here know of any Sidebar Gadgets, or Dashboard Widgets that help developers do their work? Tasks like:

- The ability to quickly look up functions/methods
- Class descriptions
- Stackoverflow questions filtered by a specific group of tags

You name it.

I'm desperately looking for a reason to use Vista's Sidebar, and I would love to do so in a way that I create a more productive environment, and helps me in my day-to-day tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the few that I actually use is [Activity Tracker](http://screeperzone.com/2007/11/25/activity-tracker-windows-vista-sidebar-time-managementtime-tracker-gadget/).  I like (sometimes have-to) keep track of my time on various projects & support tasks -- I pealed this gadget off the sidebar and dropped it on my 2nd monitor in the corner -- now, an easy click and I'm off one task and onto the next -- the web interface even graphs the time/projects.

Would love to see some more useful gadgets for sure.

Comment: That will be a great help at home, while working on multiple side-projects. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a sidebar gadget, but I have used www.quickref.org in the past to quickly looking reference. I'm sure it would make a great gadget. Unfortunately I feel the same about the Vista Sidebar, there's no real good use for it at the moment, at least for me.

Comment: Wow - that IS pretty beautiful. I'd love a sidebar gadget of that.

Answer (score 1):

I like anything that lets me unobtrusively monitor the CPU usage.  Often, for me that's simply Task Manager on a 2nd monitor or even minimized (with the activity in the system tray.)

And, (as Dad would warn) be careful about looking to use a tool just because you own it.  Kind of like applying design patterns, paradigms, etc... :)

Comment: I'm not looking for tools just for the sake of having them. I'm sincerely interested in increasing speed and productivity. If I could search a PHP/Javascript/CSS keyword from my desktop that would rock.

Comment: I understand and I hope that didn't come across as an insult!  Dad told me that because I like the new tools so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I like new technology of  desktop gadgets like Animal(Elephant), funny toy , Candle animation , etc from **www.3dfreeair.com**  try this . u also like it .